# group by with mode as aggregator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I've got a set of survey responses that I'm trying to analyze with pandas. My goal is to find (for this example) the most common gender in each county in the US, so I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
file['sex'].groupby(file['county']).agg([('modeSex', stats.mode)])
```

The output is:

[image]

How can I unpack this to only get the mode value and not the second value that tells how often the mode occurs?

Here is a sample of the data frame:

```
county|sex
----------
079   | 1
----------
079   | 2
----------
079   | 2
----------
075   | 1
----------
075   | 1
----------
075   | 1
----------
075   | 2
```

Desired output is:

```
county|modeSex
----------
079   | 2
----------
075   | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas is complaining about the returning array (I guess a pandas *cell* cannot hold a numpy array) when you use stats.mode(x)[0] so you can convert it to a list or a tuple:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"C1": np.random.randint(10, size=100), "C2": np.random.choice(["X", "Y", "Z"], size=100)})
print(df.groupby(['C2']).agg(lambda x: tuple(stats.mode(x)[0])))
```

Out:

```
     C1
C2      
X   (0,)
Y   (4,)
Z   (3,)
```

Since there can be multiple modes, if you want to keep all of them you'll need tuples or lists. If you want the first mode, you can extract that:

```
df.groupby(['C2']).agg(lambda x: stats.mode(x)[0][0])

Out:

    C1
C2    
X    0
Y    4
Z    3
```

Comment: `file['sex'].groupby(file['county']).agg({'modeSex': lambda x: stats.mode(x)[0][0]})` ended up being the winner... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

scipy.stats.mode returns `array of modal values, array of counts for each mode`
so we can use `stats.mode(a)[0]` to return only first value

here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
# sample data frame
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})
# use lambda functions
print df2.groupby(['X']).agg({'Y': lambda x:stats.mode(x)[0]})
```

output:

```
    y   
X   
A  3
B  1
```

Comment: Makes sense conceptually, but got this error: Exception: Must produce aggregated value

Comment: can you post the code along with a sample dataframe

Comment: well as per your sample dataset code is running fine on my side

Comment: It's probably a version issue. I get the same error with pandas 0.18.0.

Comment: yes may be i am running python 2.7.11 and pandas 0.17